# How to get length of elements with a certain css attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If i have an html snippet

```
<div>
     <ul style="display:block">
         <li>A</li>
         <li>B</li>
     </ul>
     <ul style="display:none">
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

How to use jQuery to find the no. of ul elements in div with a css property of `display: none`?
I know I can use `$('div').children('ul').length` but this returns all ul elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter for specific CSS values with a simple filter :

```
$('div ul').filter(function() {
    return this.style.display === 'none';
}).length
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector, if you want to get the length of hidden `ul`s. It will take care of the ones with `display:none` set. And similarly you have the `:visible` selector as well.

```
$('div').children('ul:hidden').length
```

Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Comment: Hey I noticed that if I hide the ancestor element, even if the ul elements have display: block,  :visible selector does not work as it is not seen. adeneo's solution suits my needs..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the :visible tag to find all the visible lists and then do `$('ul:visible').length` or :hidden for the opposite to find the length.